# Will an executable from FreeBSD machine work on a Solaris Machine?

Tags: unix, freebsd, solaris

I have a very basic question. I'm new to the site.

Will an executable file from a FreeBSD machine work on a Solaris machine as well?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You mention two OS's but not the hardware

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. The binary formats might be the same, but the libraries won't be a match. If you use statically linked programs, the system call convention won't match, and it will probably explode in your face.

What are you trying to do? You can install e.g. GCC on Solaris from it's extraofficial software packages, so cross-building makes little sense...